# angular-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs - tabs not visible

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use angular-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs and whenI wrap my existing bootstrap tabs, as instructed, the tabs are no longer visible. Has anyone had success with option #2 i.e., wrapping your existing bootstrap tabs with the directive? Seems pretty straight forward, not sure what the problem is. I have jquery loaded before angular and angular-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs/scrolling-tabs.j is loaded last. The only thing that renders is the < > buttons, i.e., the tabs inside are not visible. Anyone had any luck with this?

```
<div scrolling-tabs-wrapper ng-show="vm.vehicle">
<ul id="vehicle-apps-select-makes" role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
<li>model 1</li>
<li>model 2</li>
<li>model 3</li>
<li>model 4</li>
<li>model 5</li>
<li>model 6</li>
<li>model 7</li>
<li>model 8</li>
<li>model 9</li>
<li>model 10</li>
</ul>                       
</div><!-- /scrolling-tabs-wrapper -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the watch-tabs attribute fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing `<a role="tab">tab name</a>`

have you tried this?

I was kinda testing it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g261Sem8VZqPUPdML3Ms?p=preview)

Comment: I think I have some css conflict. I tried it on another page in my app and it renderd correctly.

Comment: I had to use the watch-tabs attribute.